# What is a local-only hotspot

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

I was reading up on [local-only hotspots](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-softap) and was confused by some of the language.  Am I right in my understanding that a local-only hotspot will be visible to and accessible by other phones in the physical vicinity but that there just won't be any internet provided by the network?  That's originally what I thought until I read the documentation for the [`WifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot`](https://docs.kony.com/NativeAPIs/Android/android.net.wifi-Android-10.0/index.html#!/api/android.net.wifi.WifiManager) method:

> Request a local only hotspot that an application can use to communicate between co-located devices connected to the created WiFi hotspot. The network created by this method will not have Internet access. *Each application can make a single request for the hotspot, but multiple applications could be requesting the hotspot at the same time.* When multiple applications have successfully registered concurrently, they will be sharing the underlying hotspot.

(emphasis added)

That suggests to me that the hotspot is not something that a phone would connect to like any other Wi-Fi network but that an application has to request access to somehow.

Using Android Studio, I emulated two phones and ran a simple app on one of them that uses the `WifiManager` API to start the local hotspot.  Running `ifconfig` in an `adb` shell, I see that the phone that created the hotspot gets an IPv4 address assigned to its `wlan0` interface after the hotspot is started.  I'm also able to get the app to report the hotspot's SSID ("AndroidShare_5479").  However, on the other phone, no additional entry shows up in the list of available Wi-Fi networks.

Of course, there's always the possibility that I'm using the API incorrectly.  However, that's a question better suited for StackOverflow.

My question for this community is, "What is the nature/function of a local-only hotspot?"